Filling in data as zero which is not existing in database SSRS



SCHOOL YEAR
JAN
FEB
MAR
APR
MAY
JUN
JUL
AUG




2022-2023
5
9
4
6
3
2
1
8


2023-2024
4
3
7
6
4
1
1
2


2024-2025
3
11
5
4
4
2
7
5



I have used a matrix in SSRS with schoolyear as rows, month as data and count(student) as columns.
Referred to SQL Server 2019 and 2022 SSRS
I have a select query as:
Select schoolname, datename(month, date_01) as month, student name, schoolyear
from table 1 q
join
table 2
on
q.(column)=w.(column)
where schoolyear in ('2022-2023','2023-2024','2024-2025')
group by .......
order by .....

date_01 was in yyyy/mm/dd which I converted into months.
Schoolname I have used as a parameter which as school is selected based on that my data changes.
The numbers shown are a count of student name in different months as they were registered in these months.
Now, ABC school has only data from Jan to Aug and no student was registered after that. It changes for all schools basically so no fixed pattern.



SCHOOL YEAR
JAN
FEB
MAR
APR
MAY
JUN
JUL
AUG
SEPT
OCT
NOV
DEC




2022-2023
5
9
4
6
3
2
1
8
0
0
0
0


2023-2024
4
3
7
6
4
1
1
2
0
0
0
0


2024-2025
3
11
5
4
4
2
7
5
0
0
0
0



I couldn't recall how to do this one. For schools having data in all months are okay but schools having only data for a few months is hard to show zero for other months as there is no data existing for them. Is there anything I could do in SQL Server script or SSRS?

In which month does the year change?

Basically, every month has different data. This data divided into 3 years and 12 months is based on individual students. Unfortunately for school ABC no reg done after Aug., that's why nothing can be shown after Aug. Now some other school XYZ could have data in all except November. I just have to show all moths when any school is selected with null or zero for not existing data.

An acceptable way would be to create a calendar table to use as the base table and left join your data accordingly. The snippet below achieves the same thing.
DECLARE @StartYear INT = 2022
DECLARE @EndYear INT = 2024 
DECLARE @MonthsOut INT = (@EndYear-@StartYear+1) * 12

;WITH R1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
R2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM R1 a, R1 b),
R3(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM R2 a, R2 b), 
Tally(Number) AS (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM R3)
, 
Calendar AS
(
    SELECT  
        CASE WHEN (Number % 12) = 0 THEN 12 ELSE (Number % 12) END AS [Month],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number % 12 ORDER BY Number) + @StartYear -1 AS StartYear,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number % 12 ORDER BY Number) + @StartYear  AS EndYear,
        Number AS [CalendarOrder] 
    FROM 
        Tally
    WHERE
        Number <= @MonthsOut
)
Select schoolname, datename(month, date_01) as month, student name, schoolyear
from 
Calendar cal
left join
table 1 q on datepart(month, date_01) = cal.[Month] and datepart(year, date_01)  cal.[startyear]
left join
table 2
on
q.(column)=w.(column)
where cal.schoolyear in ('2022-2023','2023-2024','2024-2025')
group by .......
order by .....,cal.CalendarOrder


I am getting an error from Tally, incorrect syntax.

Had the WHERE and FROM reversed.

My bad, first query is running fine but in the second one from Tally cal- invalid object.

Updated with Calendar CTE. The Calendar order is just for visualization and is not needed to produce results.

It worked perfectly fine; the problem still exists to show zero for Non existing data.

It is a left join so you can test the absence of data, data is null, and derive a 0 instead of null --> CASE WHEN StudentID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS CountFlag and then sum countflag at some point later.

Hi, in order to show Null data as 0, it should exist. Imagine there are two balls on the table, Blue and Black each having one. I want to show as Blue=1, Black =1 and green =0. Now this Green is not in database anywhere but still has to show as 0.Important thing here is the Month name should come up from jean to Dec whether data exists or not. I know it's weird that's what i have been asked to do.

That is why the data should be based off of the calendar. If you join all balls on month and there are no balls for, say month 3, ball_id will be null but month 3 willl still be there because it is in the base table. If ball_id is null it means there is no ball so you can derive a value of zero or if counting at a higher-level - COUNT(), the null value will not contribute to the count as if it were 0.

There is one caveat. Let's say you have Class A, Class B and Class C and both Class A and B have data for 2024-2025 but Class C does not. In that case you will have to add a dummy record for Class C (in order for it to show up under 2024-2025). There are different techniques for doing this, but I am not sure from your post this is the problem.

Got it, will try to search more. Does that thing work when data is random? I mean past 2 years data is constant but current year data's left with until September.

Meaning data is scattered randomly throughout the timespan? It does not matter until it is displayed. To display the data in a meaningful manner, a simple ORDER BY in the query itself can be used or whatever user interface component is being used to render the data will put in the order that makes most since for the desired output.

In a parameter in SSRS I have 57 schools, so each school selected, data will differ.

As long as the schools have student data along the timeline they will contribute (or simply derive as 0 if no data for a school exists). If a school does not have data along the timeline and you want it to show up in a label for display, then you will have to manufacture data with null values or something. However, it seems that you only want 0 for a month with no activity so then the above mechanism will cover all bases.

Do you mean Caveat?

Yes, simply the inverse case of the question, the case where you want all schools to display, but there is no data along the plane. Caveat, because it was not asked to be solved.

Thank you much for taking the time and helping me. .

No problem, glad I could help. if it answers your question, then please accept.
